# How do i recognize the date or date and time encoded in a string?

Tags: string, date

There's a hardware key that is used to generate a random string to enable my software and the string is valid only for a week. The string generated contains the date or date and time data. How do i recognize the date and time in the string ?

I am sure that the string contains the date and time cause i cross checked by changing my computers date and time to same as when the string was generated 3-4 months back. As i already said i can use the software by changing the system date and time. But i want to know what and how the string contains the date and time data.

The example string is below which was generated on 04/07/2019.

```
91B80ALEGN99IZ1A710ME0L80A8CG9
```

Comment: I feel that this is beyond the scope of what you can expect from SO. However, in order to determine whether there is a pattern in the 'codified' string, you would need to generate many of them

Answer (score 0):

The string you are talking about is likely to be some form of hash. Hashes are irreversible.

A good example for simple irreversible functions is a cross-sum. Pseudocode:

```
cross_sum("04/07/2019") = 0 + 4 + 0 + 7 + 2 + 0 + 1 + 9 = 23
```

How can you calculate the date "04/07/2019" from 23? You can't. Because for example:

```
cross_sum("03/08/2019") = 23
cross_sum("03/07/2020") = 23
```

For hashes, this would be a hash collision. Good hash algorithms do not have hash collisions for common or short inputs. This still does not mean that you can calcuate the original input from the hash.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Imo, I'd be surprised if the string was a hashed value.  The software would need a way to determine if the old key had expired, and there's no way it could do that without being able to understand the start date of the key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the software that decodes the string has the algorithm, so its possible !

Comment: @user2717098 The software probably doesn't decode the key. If it is written with security standards in mind, it will probably just check that the key is valid by applying some form of public/private key logic.

Comment: @Martin Which it probably does without decoding the key, I think. What's your opinion?

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt clear in my question but let me be more detailed now. There are 2 apps provided with the hardware key one for generating the string only after inserting the hardware key, and another to unlock the software when you provide the generated string. But after one week the string wont work and you gotta generate again.

Comment: @MarkusAppel It's impossible to say without knowing more about the software, but it seems highly unlikely that a _plain text_ string would contain the vital information. I tend to agree with what you've suggested

Comment: @user2717098 Hardware keys, you say? Then it is most likely a key pair that can be used to first encode the license info, then decode it. What probably happens is that when encoding the license, the encoding key is combined with the timestamp of "last Monday Midnight" or something similar. The decoding key does the same. That means that the encoded license is only valid for that duration. Bad news is: There really is no way to know what algorithm was used in encoding and decoding the license info. Your best chance is to contact the software developer.

Comment: @Markus Appeal i think you are right, most probably they have a custom created algorithm that creates the string with the date/time stamp along with the licence from the hardware key. Now the question is will it be possible to understand the "pattern" of the created string if i had some more previously created strings with the dates they were created on ? If yes i can try and post one or two more.

Comment: @user2717098 I am relatively sure that the encoded license can only be decoded with the hardware key. And even then, there is no obvious solutions that everyone uses. Chances are the software developers built it completely from scratch.

Comment: @MarkusAppel No, hardware key not required for decoding, only the software unlocking tool/app provided by the company. Edit: Its not any complicated tool, it openes in a really small window, enough for a textbox, a login button, a logout button and a check button. The check button checks for the validity of the generated string.

Comment: I think the only way would be to crack open the algorithm inside the generator/decoder tools ? Wonder its possible ?